# preg_replace - regular expression php for two different characters

Tags: php, regex

Is this a correct syntax for preg_replace (regular expression) to remove ?ajax=true or &ajax=true from a string?

```
echo preg_replace('/(\?|&)ajax=true/', '', $string);
```

So for example /hello/hi?ajax=true will give me /hello/hi and /hello/hi?ajax=true will give me /hello/hi

Do I need to escape &?

Comment: Be carefull that will replace `/hello/hi?ajax=true&foo=bar` with `/hello/hi&foo=bar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try it?

You don't need to escape "&". It is not a special character in regex.

Your expression should be working, that is an alternation that you are using. But if you have only single characters in your alternation, it is more readable, if you use a character class.

```
echo preg_replace('/[?&]ajax=true/', '', $string);
```

`[?&]` is a character class, it will match one character out of the characters listed between the square brackets.

Comment: i like that answer, explained well and your approach is easier to read. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it is ok your expression. You can add (?i) to ignore Upper Case letters. The result should be something like:

```
echo preg_replace('/(\?|&)(?i)ajax=true/', '', $string);
```

Comment: Did you not simply put `i` after the pattern's ending delimiter because you wanted `?` and `&` to be matched case-insensitively?